# How to install 'peer of @angular/core@^2.2.1'?

Tags: dependencies, ionic2, pdf-viewer, peer

In my Ionic 2 project, I try npm install ng2-pdf-viewer --save

Which results in:
 ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@2.1.1

└─┬ ng2-pdf-viewer@1.0.1

└── @types/pdf@0.0.31

npm WARN ng2-pdf-viewer@1.0.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.2.1
 but none was installed.

How can I fix this?

My package.json includes:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.1.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "1.1.6",
    "@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "ionic-angular": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "ionic-native": "2.2.3",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^1.0.1",
    "pdfjs-dist": "^1.6.483",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "ts-md5": "^1.2.0",
    "zone.js": "0.6.26"
  }
```

Comment: can you include package.json in the question?

Comment: "dependencies": {
   "@angular/common": "2.1.1",
   "@angular/compiler": "2.1.1",
   "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.1.1",
   "@angular/core": "2.1.1",
   "@angular/forms": "2.1.1",
   "@angular/http": "2.1.1",
   "@angular/platform-browser": "2.1.1",
   "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.1.1",
   "@angular/platform-server": "2.1.1",
   "@ionic/storage": "1.1.6",
   "@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
   "ionic-angular": "2.0.0-rc.3",
   "ionic-native": "2.2.3",
   "moment": "^2.17.1",
   "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^1.0.1",
   "pdfjs-dist": "^1.6.483",
   "zone.js": "0.6.26"

Comment: edit your question and add there

Answer (score 1):

To use `ng2-pdf-viewer` you need to have `angular 2.2.1` or more.
You may have to update all angular dependencies [angular/core,http,compiler-cli etc] in your package.json to `2.2.1^` and check.
You can refer to the latest ionic 2 package dependencies [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-app-base/blob/master/package.json).